# The function f is continuous on the closed interval $[0,2]$ and has values as defined by the table above. Which of the following statements are true?

Tags: calculus

> Table:
>
> $x = 0,1,2.$
>
> $f(x)= 3,4,9$

a) $f$ must be increasing on $[0,2]$

b) $f$ must be concave up on $(0,2)$

c) $f'(3/2)> f'(1/2)$

d) The average rate of increase of $f$ over $[0,2]$ is $3$.

e) $f$ has no points of inflection on $[0,2]$.

Comment: Well, there are continuous functions that aren't differentiable, so....

Comment: Which ones do you think are and why?

Comment: Have you tried computing the average rate of increase of $f$ over $[0, 2]$?

Answer (score 1):

One of them is readily verifiable by definition. None of the others can be concluded based only on our limited knowledge of $f.$

In fact, one can determine a function that is a *simultaneous* counterexample to $4$ of the $5$ statements. Try sketching some graphs of functions on $[0,2]$ with the given function values, and see if you can find counterexamples to $4$ of the $5$.

---

For a more generalizable method than "sketch some graphs and see what you can do," we can use [Lagrange interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_interpolation#Definition).

In particular, we are interested in the behavior of the function at $5$ specific points: $0,\frac12,1,\frac32,2.$ So, letting $x_j=\frac j2$ for $j=0,1,2,3,4,$ we want the graph to pass through the coordinates $\langle x_0,3\rangle,$ $\langle x_1,a\rangle,$ $\langle x_2,4\rangle,$ $\langle x_3,b\rangle,$ and $\langle x_4,9\rangle,$ where $a,b$ are some values to be determined at our convenience. The Lagrange interpolating polynomial, then, can be seen to be $$f(x)=\frac{72-8a-8b}3x^4\!+\!\frac{36a+28b-276}3x^3\!+\!\frac{330-52a-28b}3x^2\!+\!\frac{24a+8b-123}3x\!+\!3,$$ after expanding everything out and gathering like terms. Then we can see that $f'(\frac12)=-\frac{5a}3-b+12$ and $f'(\frac32)=a+\frac{5b}3-8$. These are independent linear formulas in $a,b$ and so we have the flexibility to make $f'(\frac12),f'(\frac32)$ be whatever we like. For simplicity--and to give us a counterexample to claim (c)--let's go ahead and make $f'(\frac12),f'(\frac32)=0.$ Solving the system $$\begin{cases}0=-\frac{5a}3-b+12\\0=a+\frac{5b}3-8\end{cases}$$ gives us $a=\frac{27}4,b=\frac34,$ which makes $$f(x)=4x^4-4x^3-14x^2+15x+3.$$ Then $f$ is continuous on $[0,2],$ with $f(0)=3,f(1)=4,f(2)=9,$ but $f$ is not increasing on $[0,2],$ not concave up on $(0,2),$ $f'(\frac32)=f'(\frac12),$ and $f$ has an inflection point on $[0,2].$ Thus, only claim (d) holds, and it readily holds by definition.

For a slightly different (but ultimately equivalent) approach, note that we want a continuous function with specific behavior at $5$ points, and so we can find a quartic polynomial that does the job. Start with a general quartic $f(x)=c_4x^4+c_3x^3+c_2x^2+c_1x+c_0.$ Once again, we want the graph to pass through the coordinates above, so we must solve the linear system $$\begin{cases}3=f(0)\\a=f(\frac12)\\4=f(1)\\b=f(\frac32)\\9=f(2),\end{cases}$$ that is: $$\begin{cases}3=c_0\\a=c_0+\frac12c_1+\frac14c_2+\frac18c_3+\frac1{16}c_4\\4=c_0+c_1+c_2+c_3+c_4\\b=c_0+\frac32c_1+\frac94c_2+\frac{27}8c_3+\frac{81}{16}c_4\\9=c_0+2c_1+4c_2+8c_3+16c_4.\end{cases}$$ Solving this system gets us exactly the Lagrange interpolating polynomial (without all that messy polynomial expansion to worry about), whence we can once again come up with our specific counterexample.